# Copy file to file from a list of pair of text

Tags: bash, shell, sh

My file includes:

```
a.txt b.txt
c.txt d.txt
e.txt f.txt
```

Want to do `cp a.txt b.txt` , `cp c.txt d.txt`, `cp e.txt f.txt`

What is the quick oneliner to do this ?
I try `cat file | xargs -I{} cp {}`. but it does not work since it treats the whole thing as one argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please don't call your file `file`!**

```
cat list | xargs -n 2 cp
```

Here the switch `-n 2` is crucial: it tells `xargs` to use **at  most `2` arguments per line**.

Comment: [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat). `<list xargs -n 2 cp` will do

Answer (score 0):

Why not a regular loop?

```
while read -r file1 file2 ; do
  cp -- "$file1" "$file2";
done < file
```